# Solr Master/Slave still being followed

Tags: solr, solrcloud, master-slave

I have a solr cloud cluster with three different machines. Initially when there was only one machine I had enabled replication handler for master/slave in solrconfig.xml. But then I changed the config and commented out the replication handler part. Then I add the other two machines to the cluster and also created a cluster of zookeepers(one on each machine) and uploaded the new solrconfig.xml file.

But I still see the master/slave setup on the initial machine( that one that existed from beginning) and not on the other two machines. They all have the same config now, so why is the first machine still showing the master/slave part. Do I need to reload the zookeeper for that machine or something?

Any help will be appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: did you try reload the core for that machine?

Comment: yes did that still not solved